# Diagrama de Sequência com MVC voltado para web!

Tags: modelagem, uml, diagrama

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com dúvidas em relação a alguns diagramas de sequência que estou desenvolvendo para um trabalho da faculdade.

Na teoria eu já sei o que é um diagrama de sequência, o que ele faz e qual sua finalidade, porém o problema chega na hora de modelar o mesmo!

Vou colar o meu caso de uso e logo após como o diagrama se encontra:

CASO DE USO: AGENDAR CONSULTA
ATOR PRINCIPAL: SECRETÁRIA

O caso de uso começa quando a secretária necessita agendar uma consulta para um determinado paciente;
A secretária clica no botão “procurar paciente” na página AGENDAMENTO DE CONSULTAS.
O sistema direciona para a página BUSCA DE PACIENTES CADASTRADOS.
A secretária digita o nome do paciente ou parte dele e pressiona a tecla “enter”.
O sistema exibe em uma tabela os pacientes encontrados.
A secretária marca o checkbox do respectivo paciente e clica no botão “confirmar”.
O sistema retorna para a página AGENDAMENTO DE CONSULTAS.
A secretária clica no ícone do calendário do campo “data consulta”.
O sistema exibe as datas disponíveis do mês corrente.
A secretária seleciona a data desejada.
A secretária clica no ícone do calendário do campo “hora consulta”.
O sistema exibe as horas disponíveis da data selecionada.
A secretária seleciona a hora desejada.
A secretária clica no botão “agendar”.
O sistema retorna a mensagem “Consulta agendada com sucesso”.

[image: Diagrama sequencia]

O problema é que eu estou achando que faltam coisas.

Lembrando que estou modelando o projeto tentando usar da arquitetura MVC e que o projeto seja um webapp!
Algumas sugestões? Fotos do wireframe

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]